# Android request with cyrillic characters

Tags: java, android, http

A need to send http request with cyrillic characters.
In string "text" i have a russian word. It encoded final address, but connection.getInputStream() throws exception. With english words it works correctly. Encoded URL (address) normally opens in browser.
Here a code:

```
    String text = params[0] ;
    try {
        text = URLEncoder.encode(text, HTTP.UTF_8) ;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace() ;
    }
    String address = "http://"+text+".jpg.to" ;
    String result = "" ;
    BufferedReader reader = null ;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(address) ;
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection() ;
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream() ;
        InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8") ;
        reader = new BufferedReader(inReader) ;

        String inputLine = null ;
        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result+inputLine ;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace() ;
    } finally {        
        try {
            reader.close() ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Are you solve this problem? I have the same thing also.